# URLDownloadToFile C++ won't download more than 15Kb

Tags: c++, winapi, download, max-size

```
void UpdateApp(HWND hwnd) {
HRESULT hRez = URLDownloadToFile( NULL, string("Web Address here.").c_str(), string("Download file here").c_str(), 0, NULL);
if(hRez == E_OUTOFMEMORY ){
    MessageBox(hwnd, "","",MB_OK);
}
else if(hRez!=S_OK) {
    MessageBox(hwnd, "Error downloading the updater.", "Error!", MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
}
if(hRez==S_OK) {
    MessageBox(hwnd, "Done", "", MB_OK);
}
}
```

I am making an auto-update program for a main program. So far all is going good, but the function URLDownloadToFile does not download more than 14.1 Kb. I am using it to download a zip with all the update files in it. Every time I run it it goes 14.1 Kb and then stops, and doesn't return any errors. I haven't read anywhere about a size restriction on the downloads, so what could be causing this? The actual size of the zip is 1,644Kb. Thanks for any and all help in advance.

Comment: What are you actually receiving? Are you sure it's not some form of meta-data describing the resource you're trying to access?

Comment: Wow... I always look over the simplest things. I had a wrong letter in the download url, so instead of downloading the zip file it was downloading the File Not Found page -_-.

Comment: Haha yeah that's about 15kb worth :)